# ロリポップFTPでLPを公開するやり方を教えてください

Tags: ftp

ロリポップにHTMLとCSSとIMGを移したんですが、うまく反映されません。何がダメなのか全くわからないので、ぜひご教授ください。

Comment: 質問が短すぎて何が問題なのかを把握したり再現・調査・回答するのに必要な具体的な情報が書かれていません。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問を改善してください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

まずはロリポップ！サーバーのマニュアルをご覧ください。たとえば、

- [アップロードしよう](https://lolipop.jp/manual/startup/upload/)
- [独自ドメイン設定](https://lolipop.jp/manual/user/chg-plan/)
- [他サーバーからの移行方法](https://lolipop.jp/manual/startup/iten/)

あたりが参考になるでしょう。

これより詳しい回答は、現状のざっくりとした質問文だと難しいです。「うまく反映されない」とはどういう状況でしょうか。何かがうまくいかないとして、どういう状態にしたいのに、実際はどういう状態になるのか、より詳しく説明するようにして新しく質問してみてください。